# Sideloading/installing windows store application

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store-app, side-loading

I have a windows 8.1 universal application with cpu archs specific dependencies.

As i understand i can use Add-AppxProvisionedPackage to install an application without installing the certificate in my trust store ? (not sure about this) and skipping the licencse.

i logged into a win 8.1 tablet with administrator rights.
I ran this command Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath C:\MyApp.appx -DependencyPackagePath C:\Depepdencypath -SkipLicense.

It returned the result of 
Path           :
Online         : True
Restart Needed : False

But i cannot see my application in the tiles. Do i have to login as a separate user ? but shouldn't admin also able to view it ?

My machine has the developer license installed though but not the certificate.
I am kind of confused with this cmdlet.

cheers,

Saurav

Answer (score 1):

From the thread
[How to re-install a provisioned package?](http://www.networksteve.com/windows/topic.php/How_to_re-install_a_provisioned_package/?TopicId=64963&Posts=2)
comes this advice :

> Please try the following command to bring it back :
>
> ```
> import-module appx
> add-appxpackage SampleApp
> ```
>
> The add-AppxProvisionedPackage command line is used to deploy the
>   packages for all the users in the machine and the add-appxpackage
>   command line is used for specific user.